# Relationship between form and formset on same webpage

Tags: python, django, forms, foreign-key-relationship, formset

I'm trying to relate all the objects created in a formset to an object created on the same webpage as the formset. So, an example of the code is this:

```
def create_b(request):
    SpeciesFormSet = modelformset_factory(Species, fields=('common', 'scientific'))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = SpeciesFormSet(request.POST)
        form1 = BForm(request.POST)
        if form1.is_valid():
            objcreate = BModel.objects.create(
                                name = form1.cleaned_data['name'],
                                ...
                                )
            objcreate.save()
            for forms in formset.forms:
                if forms.is_valid():
                    formset1 = Species.objects.create (
                                common = forms.cleaned_data['common'],
                                scientific = forms.cleaned_data['scientific'],
                                BName = form1.cleaned_data['name']
                                )
                    formset1.save()
                else:
                    formset = SpeciesFormSet()
                    form1 = BForm()
                    c = {'SpeciesFormSet' : SpeciesFormSet, 'form1' : form1}
                    c.update(csrf(request))
                    return render_to_response('Forms/create_b.html', c)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/accounts/profile')
    else:
        formset = SpeciesFormSet()
        form1 = BForm()
    c = {'SpeciesFormSet' : SpeciesFormSet, 'form1' : form1}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('Forms/create_b.html', c)
```

The problem I'm having is that when trying to relate the formset object to the form one, it tells me that the form object doesn't actually exist. It creates the object in the database however, just none of the formset objects. I get the error "Cannot assign "u''": "Species.BName" must be a "BModel" instance." if that helps. Also, the relationship is a ForeignKey. Is there anyway to solve this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact pattern is what [inline model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets) are for.

Answer (score 0):

From the error, it looks like you are assigning a BName where the property is supposed to be a BModel. Either, you want to change the BName with a BModel, or you need to fix your models so they match with a BName for the Species.

```
formset1 = Species.objects.create (
    common = forms.cleaned_data['common'],
    scientific = forms.cleaned_data['scientific'],
    BName = form1.cleaned_data['name']
)
formset1.save()
```

Comment: BName is a field in the Species model, it's a ForeignKey relationship to the BModel through the name field. Models are all fine, it's just that the database doesn't have the BModel saved fast enough or something along those lines, not entirely sure.